# pipe followed by .$var into function, why doesnt this work?

Tags: r, dplyr, magrittr

Can someone tell me why example 1 is not working but example 2 works?
(I pipe a data set into mean function, but want only one variable, 
but if I do the selection first and pipe the result there is no problem)

```
iris %>% mean(.$Sepal.Length)
```

> NA
>      Warning message:
>      In mean.default(., .$Sepal.Length) :
>      argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

```
iris %>% .$Sepal.Length %>% mean()

 5.843333
```

Comment: You can use `summarise` to apply functions i.e. `iris %>% summarise(val=mean(Sepal.Length))  %>% .$val`

Comment: thanks @akrun, but I was not actually looking for a way to apply the mean function to my data frame, the second part does, but wondering why version 1 doesn't work while version 2 does

Comment: I guess it is evaluating the mean before the `.$Sepal.Length` and `mean` will work on a `vector` or `matrix`.  You can also check `iris %>% mean()`

Comment: That's a interesting idea @akrun! Indeed the error message with `iris %>% mean( )` looks the same. So the order of evaluation is mean first and then the dot?

Comment: Another approach is `iris %>% with(., mean(Sepal.Length))`

Comment: @akrun i bet there's no need for `.,` in the `with` but no R to test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you unpipe your code

```
iris %>% mean(.$Sepal.Length)
```

becomes

```
mean(iris, iris$Sepal.Length)
```

Essentially, you're trying to apply `mean` to a `data.frame` and there's no method for doing that.

The unpiped equivalent of

```
iris %>% .$Sepal.Length %>% mean()
```

is

```
mean(iris$Sepal.Length)
```

And there *is* a method of `mean` for numeric vectors.

Remember that in a pipe, the entire object on the left hand side of the pipe is passed to the first argument on the right hand side (unless otherwise represented by `arg = .`).  Trying to pass only part of the object tends not to work so well.

Comment: right, and in magrittr-style piping it would probably be `iris %$% Sepal.Length %>% mean`

Comment: Oh how I love `magrittr`.  I need to learn to use `%$%` more often. (I'm guilty of having used `iris %>% `$(Sepal.Length)` %>% mean`, which just looks so wrong.

Comment: Thanks @Benjamin ! It is a bit weird that `%>% .$var` is represented as `df, df$var`.

Comment: I often fall back on magrittr, @docendodiscimus, for these kind of operations, but it sort of breaks the flow in a chain of commands:
`df %>%
filter(df) %>%
select(df) %$%
mean(var)`